# Is there a program to balance single-threaded programs across a cluster?

Tags: multithreading, cluster-computing, raspbian

As I understand it, most standard programs, like games, don't benefit from clusters because they don't have additional threads to disperse the load. Specifically I'm looking at a Raspberry Pi cluster. My question is this: Is there a program, I suppose similar to an emulator or Virtual Machine, that can be 'spread' across the nodes, connecting them like how a spiderweb might connect several objects and span the gap between them?

The reasoning behind my question is that if a given program can't be multi-threaded, then perhaps there could be a bridging program to connect them, within which you could run a single-threaded program, treating the nodes as if they were really one more powerful computer.

Failing this, is there a hardware solution instead? E.g: directly linking together parts of several boards (I know how bad that example is, it's just the only example I can think of). Thank you for your time.

Comment: In a sense this is done inside a high power single core cpu(the way you get more single core performance is to do many instructions at once ), but in general the program has to  have been written with concurrency/parallelism in mind to be used on many cores/computers. Automatically rewrite programs into a more parallel form is an active research area.

Comment: what about stacking lesser CPUs in a fashion similar to RAID for hard drives?

Comment: How exactly would that work from an implementation standpoint? RAID works by alternating which drives blocks are placed on to allow faster read/write since a n block file now takes as long to read/write as the slowest drive does (n/(number of drives) blocks. You can't really arbitrarily split work across many processors without having threading

Comment: i was under the impression that there was a way to connect lesser cpus to make them work like a single greater one. i guess i'll have to settle for higher-quality components and optane. thanks for the advice.